# problem passing variable to php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I really dont know why this isnt working!

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateVAL()
{
var f = document.getElementById("nu");
var val=f.value;
alert(val); // it displays the value properly 
$.post("getDATA.php", {id: val}); // I sent the variable with jquery
}

</script>
```

**getDATA.php**

```
$value=$_POST['id'];
echo $value;
```

and when I access getDATA.php to see if it was sent I get this:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Users\dan...

why the variable 'id' isnt set ? why is isnt passed to the server ?

Any help would be appreciated :)
Cheers,

dan.

Comment: What does `val` contain?

Comment: When you say *when I access getDATA.php to see if it was sent* do you mean via Firebug or Web Inspector?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but did you try to put quotes in `id`? Like this:
`$.post("getDATA.php", {"id": val});`

Comment: try putting `$_POST['id']` to some file instead of `echo`. i guess you will see it.

Comment: try changing `{id: val}` to `{"id": val}`

Comment: Definitely install firebug. It makes troubleshooting things like this much easier.

Comment: "when I access getDATA.php to see if it was sent", how???

Comment: According to jQuery documentation you don't need to enclose the data name with quotes. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post

Comment: I access getDATA.php by the url

Comment: I tried with the "id" and 'id' but it didnt work :S

Comment: i dont know what is firebug... im gonna take a look thx !

Comment: IF you access getData.php by the URL you are definitely not passing `id` through the `POST`. Install Firebug and use `Net` pane to see, if you are really passing the variable and what outuput is.

Comment: thx JOHN Im going to do a quick search on Firebug

Comment: i did the debug and its passing the variable:

POST
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
id 16
Source
id=16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are being sent via ajax - so this `js` script calls `getDATA.php` and `$_POST['id']` is "seen" there only at that time.

And you are trying to access `getDATA.php` after and send no `post` or `get` parameters by your briwser - so you don't see this params there.

You have to catch `echo` by your `js` script. Look at this demo:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Comment: ohhh I understand now!
I did what u said and the value was retrieved to js after it was echoed by getDATA.php

many thx to u and all that helped :)